# How to validate a field with uppercase with django serializers

Tags: python, django

I am programming an API and I have noticed the following error when debugging.
The following code does not validate the Status field

```
class DocumentSalesforceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    AccountId = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    ContactId = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    Status = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    StartDate = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    EndDate = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=True)
    Subject = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate_status(self, Status):
        if Status not in ("New", "In Progress", "On Hold", "Completed", "Closed", "Cannot Complete", "Canceled"):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid Status")
        return Status
```

But, when I change the word "Status" to "status" like this:

```
class DocumentSalesforceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    AccountId = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    ContactId = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    status = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    StartDate = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    EndDate = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=True)
    Subject = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate_status(self, status):
        if status not in ("New", "In Progress", "On Hold", "Completed", "Closed", "Cannot Complete", "Canceled"):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid Status")
        return status
```

Everything is working perfectly fine.
Can anyone tell me why is it working like that and how can I do to validate the "Status" uppercase field? Thanks

Comment: It should be `validate_Status`, so with the uppercase in the method as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code does not validate the Status field.

It expects that the validator is named `validate_Status`, so with an uppercase `S` as well:

```
class DocumentSalesforceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    AccountId = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    ContactId = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    Status = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    StartDate = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    EndDate = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=True)
    Subject = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    def validate_Status(self, Status):
        if Status not in ("New", "In Progress", "On Hold", "Completed", "Closed", "Cannot Complete", "Canceled"):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid Status")
        return Status
```